# Flutter android app doesn't have internet connection

Tags: android, flutter, dart, url-launcher

I built an flutter app. I used url_launcher package to navigate social links and other external browser links. And it was perfectly working on android emulator. But when I build the apk and install it on my mobile phone, URLs didn't launch. Even the network images aren't showing up.

Simply I mean the flutter app did not have internet access at all. My question is why the same code working on emulator perfectly and doesn't work on a real device?

I also checked android manifest file. There were no problems also.
Here is the android manifest code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sri_lanka">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

And here is the icon button that won't open on a real mobile
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYTmU.png

Comment: Here you will need to do some troubleshooting yourself. Open your Android phone's web browser (usually Chrome) and navigate to a random website that you know does exist. Are you able to do that? Or is the Android phone having trouble with network connections in general?

Comment: NO. My mobile phone was working correctly. To make sure the mobile is fine, I installed the apk on several devices. I had the same issue as I expected which is "URLs not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:
You need to add some extra coding in to your android manifest to launch URLs on a real device.
You can also refer to the url_launcher documentation https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

please refer to this link to get detailed information https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#kotlin

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4VQR.png)

And you need to add another line of code to manifest file in order to access internet on android mobile.

this is it =>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is the code you need to add in to the android manifest:
manifest file path => android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app makes calls -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app sends emails -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like AndroindManifest.xml of debug version. try adding the same line
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
to AndroidManifest.xml in main folder

[image]

Comment: I tried as you said. Now I can view network images. Which means now my app has internet access. But still I can not launch URLs. How ever thank you very much for your help

Comment: It might be because of the condition, you can remove the condition "canLaunch" and forcefully launch the URLs.

Comment: I had to add some extra lines of coding to solve this issue. refer to this=> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71186344/17377657 . Thank you very much for your help